# Aligning tags in a table [Latex]

Tags: latex

I am using the following code to create a table in Latex:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{Example table.}
\label{tab:model-testbed}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
Comment                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Device1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Device2}                \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}BlaBla \\ Sth \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
   \begin{equation}
     \tag{1}\label{t3:1}
     \begin{aligned}
      y(x) = 66.1 + 1.11x - 1.28 \times 10^{-8}x^2 \\ +15.08 \times 10^{-2}x^1
      \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
  \begin{equation}
      \tag{2}\label{t3:2}
      \begin{aligned}
          y(x) =20.33 + 1.24y - 1.74 \times 10^{-1}x^5 \\ + 1.14 \times 10^{-7}y^5
      \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
  \end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}BlaBla \\ Sth\end{tabular}        & 
\begin{equation}
    \tag{3}\label{t3:3}
    \begin{aligned}
            w(x) =2.13 + 0.03x 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
& 
\begin{equation}
    \tag{4} \label{t3:4}
    \begin{aligned}
            er(x) =4.85 + 33.56y
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
                          \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}BlaBla\\  Sth\end{tabular}   & 
\begin{equation}
    \tag{5}\label{t3:5}
    \begin{aligned}
        b(x) =12.2 + 5.20y             
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
& 
\begin{equation}
    \tag{6}\label{t3:6}
    \begin{aligned}
        a(x) =1.11 + 1.11x - 2.543 \times 10^{-2}x^2
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

And it outputs the following table:
[image: pic1]
I am struggling to find a way how to align the tags. As you can see next to each formula there is a tag (1), (3), etc. , and it is positioned right next to the equation. But, I would like all the tags to be aligned. I tried with `\hspace{1cm}` to try to move them to the left, hoping that I can position them to the end of the column and with it align them, but it did not work.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to wrap "display" equations inside `minipage`s. The tags would correctly be pushed to the right. However, equations get centred w.r.t. surrounding environment.

One way to achieve left alignment with right tags is to add equations in-line  and then use `\tag{}` separately. However, the latter is not allowed outside equations. It can be sorted out by manually setting the `@currentlabel` for very next `\label{}` usage; I have made a macro for that--its optional star removes parentheses in case you don't want them.

A couple remarks. I added `geometry` to increase the page width for demonstration because this table gets quite wide. Sometimes, environments like equations cause issues with the standard vertical spacing and this needs a manual adjustment. There are other table-related packages that sort it out, e.g. `tabularray` but here I have used a strut: `\xmathstrut{factor}` from `mathtools`. Also, for multi lined texts, I'd suggest to use `\makecell` from `makecell`--a very convenient macro that allows line breaks. EDIT. the vertical spacing could also be sorted by increasing so-called "gape" inside makecells--I'll leave it for you.

Here's the example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\refanchor{sm}{
  % #1 star removes partheses
  % #2 reference label
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{(}#2\IfBooleanF{#1}{)}
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
References: eq.~\ref{t3:1} on page \pageref{t3:1}.

References with parentheses: eq.~\eqref{t3:3} on page \pageref{t3:3}.


\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \small
  \centering
  \caption{Example table.}\label{tab:model-testbed}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l@{}|l@{}|}
    \hline
    Comment 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Device1}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Device2} \\
    \hline
    \makecell{BlaBla\\Sth}
    &
      \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \(\xmathstrut{1.25}
        \begin{aligned}
          y(x) = 66.1 + 1.11x - 1.28 \times 10^{-8}x^2 \\
          +15.08 \times 10^{-2}x^1
        \end{aligned}\)%
        \hfill
        \refanchor{1}\label{t3:1}
      \end{minipage}
    &
      \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \(
        \begin{aligned}
          y(x) =20.33 + 1.24y - 1.74 \times 10^{-1}x^5\\
          +1.14 \times 10^{-7}y^5
        \end{aligned}\)
        \hfill
        \refanchor{2}\label{t3:2}
      \end{minipage} \\
    \hline
    \makecell{BlaBla\\Sth}  
    & 
      \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \(\xmathstrut{1.15} w(x) =2.13 + 0.03x \)%
        \hfill
        \refanchor{3}\label{t3:3}
      \end{minipage}
    &
      \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \(er(x) = 4.85 + 33.56y\)%
        \hfill
        \refanchor*{4}\label{t3:4}
      \end{minipage}
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]